# How to highlight a particular ( important ) it block in the report while running protractor script?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I have around 10 it blocks in my spec. Among these, Two it blocks are testing important features and I want to highlight these in my report so that I can immediately sense whether those features are working fine or not. Is there any way 
 to achieve this?

I am using jasmine reporter with protractor for reporting.

Comment: Are you using the default Jasmine reporter?

Answer (score 0):

Try the reporter below for better reporting

https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-html-reporter-2

For better view on the report make a separate `describe` for the particular `it` blocks.

Hope it helps you